# Issue with returning a query from firestore

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, dialogflow-es

Why is a return statement necessary to read data from firestore? When I use let userRef.get()... nothing is printed to the console.

Thanks.

Comment: `return` only makes sense in the context of a function. What's the function this is inside of, and what's the code that's calling it?

Comment: *"Why is a return statement necessary to read data from firestore?"* It isn't. We need more context. It sounds, for instance, like you may have been looking for the output too soon when you didn't have the `return`, since the caller wouldn't have a promise to wait on.

Comment: You can't just add `let` in front of a function call

Comment: Please edit the question to more fully show your code, and the specific line that's responsible for the error you're seeing.

Comment: It will also help if you show the exact error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a google cloud function, you need to return a promise for the result of your function. If you do something asynchronous (like reading from firestore) and do not return the appropriate promise, the runner kills your function before it has finished.

Comment: While this is true, it might not be relevant. We haven't yet seen all the relevant code here.  For all we know the OP is in fact returning the right promise from the function, but eslint could be complaining about something else (such as the lack of a return from the `then` callback).

Comment: @DougStevenson Yes, the question is a bit unclear, but with reasonable assumptions I decided that what started as a comment would actually make an answer :-) Why do you mention eslint?

Comment: Because eslint will warn against `then` callbacks that don't themselves return a value.  eslint is enabled by default on Cloud Functions projects, and it will check for missing return promises.  That's more likely the problem here.  But without more comprehensive code and an error message that indicates the line number, it's still ambiguous.

Comment: @DougStevenson Well OP says "*nothing is printed to the console*", not "*a linter warning appears*"

Comment: That's because this is a probably a compile time error generated by eslint, not a runtime error.  Why would a runtime error complain about a missing return?

Comment: https://github.com/xjamundx/eslint-plugin-promise/blob/HEAD/docs/rules/always-return.md

Comment: @DougStevenson I understood from the question that the OP simply tried out omitting/adding the `return` keyword in front of `cityRef.get()…`, and found that one works (printing the expected firestore values) and the other doesn't.

Comment: I'm actually trying to get the data from within Dialogflow fulfilment. The issue I have is that i can't quite figure out where to put agent.add();